# Function Check if Worksheet Exists

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that checks whether or not a worksheet named `wsName` exists already in the workbook. The issue I am having is getting the function to run with the restructuring and removal of `On Error Resume Next`. What I am expecting is the macro to run and produce copies of the worksheets that do not already exist in the workbook and if the worksheets do already exist, then print out `ErrorMsg` saying `"Unknown Error"`. What I see however, is the macro print out the `ErrorMsg` even if the worksheet does not exist and makes a copy of it. I am trying this approach to `SheetExists` to see if there is a way to get the function to run without using `On Error Resume Next` as I do not want to macro to ignore errors that are generated, rather I would want it to print out `"Unknown Error"`

```
Global Parameter As Long, RoutingStep As Long, wsName As String, version As String, ErrorMsg As String, SDtab As Worksheet
Global wb As Workbook, sysrow As Long, sysnum As String, ws As Worksheet

Public Sub Main()
    Dim syswaiver As Long, axsunpart As Long
    Dim startcell As String, cell As Range
    Dim syscol As Long, dict As Object, wbSrc As Workbook

Set wb = Workbooks("SD3_KW.xlsm")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Data Sheet") 


syswaiver = 3
axsunpart = 4


Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open("Q:\Documents\Specification Document.xlsx")
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary") 

If Not syswaiver = 0 Then
    startcell = ws.cells(2, syswaiver).Address 
Else
    ErrorMsg = "waiver number column index not found. Value needed to proceed"
    GoTo Skip
End If

For Each cell In ws.Range(startcell, ws.cells(ws.Rows.Count, syswaiver).End(xlUp)).cells 
    sysnum = cell.value
    sysrow = cell.row
    syscol = cell.column
    
    If Not dict.Exists(sysnum) Then 
        dict.Add sysnum, True
    
        If Not SheetExists(sysnum, wb) Then 
            If Not axsunpart = 0 Then
                wsName = cell.EntireRow.Columns(axsunpart).value 
                If SheetExists(wsName, wbSrc) Then 
                    wbSrc.Worksheets(wsName).copy After:=ws 
                    wb.Worksheets(wsName).Name = sysnum 
                Set SDtab = wb.Worksheets(ws.Index + 1)
                Else
                    ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg & IIf(ErrorMsg = "", "", "") & "part number for " & sysnum & " sheet to be copied could not be found"
                    cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
                GoTo Skip
                End If
      Else
                ErrorMsg = "part number column index not found. Value needed to proceed"
            End If 
            
        Else 
            MsgBox "Sheet " & sysnum & " already exists."
        End If
    End If
    
Skip:

Dim begincell As Long, logsht As Worksheet 
Set logsht = wb.Worksheets("Log Sheet") 
    With logsht ' wb.Worksheets("Log Sheet")
        begincell = .cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        .cells(begincell + 1, 3).value = sysnum
        .cells(begincell + 1, 3).Font.Bold = True
        .cells(begincell + 1, 2).value = Date
        .cells(begincell + 1, 2).Font.Bold = True

        If Not ErrorMsg = "" Then
            .cells(begincell + 1, 4).value = vbNewLine & "Complete with Erorr - " & vbNewLine & ErrorMsg
            .cells(begincell + 1, 4).Font.Bold = True
            .cells(begincell + 1, 4).Interior.Color = vbRed
        Else
            .cells(begincell + 1, 4).value = "All Sections Completed without Errors"
            .cells(begincell + 1, 4).Font.Bold = True
            .cells(begincell + 1, 4).Interior.Color = vbGreen
        End If
    End With

Next Cell 

End Sub
```

```
Function SheetExists(SheetName As String, wb As Workbook)  
On Error GoTo Message
SheetExists = Not wb.Sheets(SheetName) Is Nothing
Exit Function
Message:
    ErrorMsg = "Unknown Error"
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function code reaches **always** the last line, in the way it is...

You must place a code line to exit function if the sheet object exists:

```
Function SheetExists_(SheetName As String, wb As Workbook) As Boolean
On Error GoTo Message
SheetExists_ = Not wb.Sheets(SheetName) Is Nothing
If Not wb.Sheets(SheetName) Is Nothing Then Exit Function
Message:
    MsgBox "Unknown Error"
End Function
```

**Edited**:

```
Function SheetExists_(SheetName As String, wb As Workbook) As Boolean
On Error GoTo Message
SheetExists_ = Not wb.Sheets(SheetName) Is Nothing: Exit Function

Message:
    'reaching this part will (only) make it returning `False`...
End Function
```

Please, take care that the above function is `SheetExists_`. It has an underscore character of the name end. I have another function with this  name...

Comment: I tried that, unfortunatley it did not work and still prints `ErrorMsg` despite the worksheet not existing in the workbook.

Comment: @resu_student In fact, you can. If not an error before, the code will exit. I only wanted to show a didactic way, to clearly understand in which conditions the function code will be exited...

Comment: Was it able to run when you tried?

Comment: I did not try but I am sure it will work. I will edit the above code and show you where exactly to exit...

Comment: I copied it exactly how you wrote it, but it still it not exiting and prints out `ErrorMsg` When I replace the line `On Error GoTo Message` with `On Error Resume Next` it works, but I do not want to use `On Error Resume Next` because it ignores all errors

Comment: @resu_student If you copied it **exactly as it is** and you call it using `SheetExists_` (see the last underscore character) it should work. Now, I will close my laptop and leave my office... And, if you use `On Error Resume Next` it is mandatory to use `On Error GoTo 0` after trying to set the sheet object.

Comment: It is not. It just prints out the `MsgBox` for every worksheet when it shouldnt be.

Comment: Please, check the wb you pass as second parameter... I am driving

Comment: There are different `wb` that are passed depending on when the function is called. For debugging purposes, there are no worksheets in the workbooks with the same name as `SheetName` therefore no `ErrorMsg` should be produced.

Comment: @resu_student Do you have TeamViewer of AnyDesk installed? If so, I would like to connect to your computer and try understanding what's happening in your installation.

Answer (score 0):

Your "SheetExists" function will always set "ErrorMsg" to "Unknown Error".  Add "Exit Function" after
`SheetExists = Not wb.Sheets(SheetName) Is Nothing`

Comment: I already tried that and it did not work. I updated my code to show how I added `Exit Function`

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it now, you set ErrorMsg to "Unknown Error" when the sheet doesn't exist. That's why you'll get the error with every sheet since every sheet is different in your test-setup.
Your function will still give a False (doesn't exist) but also the error.

**EDIT:**

If you want to have ErrorMsg to have "Unknown Error" when it exists, you need to implement it when the On Error Goto Message *isn't* triggered, like so:

```
Function SheetExists(SheetName As String, wb As Workbook)
    On Error GoTo Message
    SheetExists = Not wb.Sheets(SheetName) Is Nothing
    ErrorMsg = "Unknown Error" 'sheet exists
    Exit Function
Message: 'sheet doesn't exist, SheetExists remains false and no errormsg required
End Function
```

Comment: How do I get it to only set `ErrorMsg = "Unknonw Error"` when the sheet does already exist

Comment: Edited my Answer, it's just moving the ErrorMsg to where it does exist while keeping the skip for when wb.Sheets(SheetName) does give an error (sheet doesn't exist).

Comment: Since `Message` displays nothing, then what is the purpose of having `On Error GoTo Message`?

Comment: To exit the function without setting the ErrorMsg, aka skipping the rest of the code.

Comment: Oh so is that for when the sheet does exist?

Comment: It's for when it does NOT exist. If it doesn't it causes the "On Error GoTo Message" to skip setting  your ErrorMsg. If it does exist, there is no error when you use wb.Sheets(SheetName).

Comment: Oh okay, I think where I am running into an error is when I call the function I say `If Not SheetExists(sysnum, wb) Then` so I want the sheet to not exist already. Thats probably why it is telling me it fails everytime because the `ErrorMsg` is being generated.

Comment: `If Not SheetExists(sysnum, wb) Then ` is correct. `If NOT` is needed since `SheetExists(sysnum, wb)` will return TRUE if the sheet does exist. In that If-statement, you need the Not so you get in the if-statement when the sheet does not exist. If you use my EDIT code, you should be fine and only copy the sheets that don't exist yet in wb from the sheets that do exist in wbSrc.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple function to check. And you shall not confuse sheet with worksheet

```
Public Function sh_Exist(TheWorkbook As Workbook, SheetName As String) As Boolean
Dim s As String
On Error GoTo errHandler
s = TheWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName).Name
sh_Exist = True
Exit Function
errHandler:
End Function
```